# Meaning of 'stabs-sick eyes'

Tags: meaning, punctuation

From "Red Wind" by Raymond Chandler:

> He lowered them slowly and looked at the man on the floor. The man's neck was twitching a little. His eyes moved in **short stabs-sick eyes**.
>
> "Sure it's the guy?" Copernik's voice was hoarse.

What exactly  are 'stabs-sick' eyes?

Comment: _stabs – sick_ not _stabs-sick_, dash, not hyphen. Changes meaning.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In this excerpt from Raymond Chandler's [*Red Wind,*](http://design.caltech.edu/erik/Misc/Red_Wind-Raymond_Chandler.pdf) I suspect you may have been misled by what looks like a hyphen, but I think is actually an ineptly formatted dash.

I have used curly brackets below to group together what I consider to be the components of the sense units of the sentence in question:

> {His eyes moved} {in short stabs} — {sick eyes}.

Chandler's dash introduces a parenthetical description of the man's eyes. It could be  rephrased thus:

> He moved his sick eyes in short stabs

or

> His sick eyes moved in short stabs.

Comment: I happen to have just picked up from the library a published collection containing this story (Raymond Chandler, *Collected Stories*, Everyman's Library edition, Knopf) and indeed it is a dash.

Answer (score 6):

You have mistranscribed this, or drawn from a mistranscribed source. The original has a dash, not a hyphen.

> His eyes moved in short stabs—sick eyes.

The basic clause is *His eyes moved in short stabs*. That is, the direction of his glance moved abruptly from one object to another, as if 'stabbing' the objects viewed. *Sick eyes* is added to this clause as a further characterization of his eyes: they were 'sick' eyes.